# Assign extension methods to a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to assign a variable to an extension method, but getting the error when I hover over the line.

`cannot assign 'void' to an implicitly-typed local variable`

I am checking for empty fields and calling my extension method and wanted to check more than one field and if they were all failing I wanted them to appear in one error box instead of them piling up.

```
if (drp_SelectGroup.SelectedValue == "0")
{
  var message =  this.ShowMessage("Select an Ethnic Group", "ERROR", ErrorType.error);
}
```

Edit*

```
public static void ShowMessage(this Page page, string message, string title, ErrorType err)
    {
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "toastr",
            String.Format("toastr.{0}('{1}','{2}');", err, message, title), addScriptTags: true);
    }
```

Comment: Where's the extension method? Which call in there is the call to the extension method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that it's an extension method - it's that the extension method has a `void` return type. Presumably that method *shows* the message, rather than just creating it. You'd get exactly the same error message if you tried to call any other void method and assign the result to a variable.

You probably need to change your extension method to something like this:

```
public static string GetMessage(this Whatever foo, string message, string type,
                                ErrorType errorType)
```

Comment: When I try string it says return type is missing. do I just `return` page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "toastr",
                String.Format("toastr.{0}('{1}','{2}');", err, message, title), addScriptTags: true);

Comment: @StudentRik: Well we really don't know what your code is meant to achieve - you've given us basically no context here. Work out what you want to return, and return it... understanding that the fact that it's an extension method is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know how I would do this. Can you point me to any resources.

Comment: @StudentRik: How you would do what? Writing a method which returns a value is pretty fundamental to writing *any* C# code - if you're sufficiently new to C# that you get stuck at that point, you should avoid extension methods for the moment. (There's nothing wrong with being new, but take one step at a time.)

Answer (score 2):

From the error it looks like `ShowMessage` has a `void` return type.

That means that it isn't returning anything.

You are trying to assign that nothing type to a variable.

Solution:

Change the signature of `ShowMessage` to return what you need it to return.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of this method is: `void`. You can not assign a type `void` to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ShowMessage("Select an Ethnic Group", "ERROR", ErrorType.error);
```

appears to have a return type of `void`. You cannot then assign to a local variable (`var message`)

You can change the return type of `Show.Message()` and this should work for you.